# Dual discounted forward curve

Tags: swaps, forward-rate, ois-discounting, discount-factor-curve, discounting

I was wondering how to calculate the forward rates based on OIS discounting for the half year terms. I know how to do this for the full year terms -> just making sure that the two legs are equal to each other. 
The problem is that I don't have fixed payments on the half year terms. For example when one wants to calculate the 1,5 OIS discounted forward rate you only have 1 fixed payment versus 3 floating payments. How to deal with this? 
One method which can be used is just calculating the full year rates and then interpolate between these rates, but I wonder if there is a method which can calculate these rates without using interpolation?

Next to that what does a 1,5 swap rate exactly mean, is this just an interpolated rate because you will have the same problem here when there isn't a payment on the half years.

Comment: What do you mean "you only have 1 fixed payment versus 3 floating payments". I have never heard about this new kind of swap.

Comment: I don't think this kind of swap is really common but it's more a fake instrument to calculate the forward rates based on OIS discounting.

Answer (score 3):

Which currency are you looking at ? 
Say that your 1y swap would have yearly fixed payments vs 3M floating payments. 
Your 1.5y swap would probably have:

- a fixed payment 6m after effective date and another fixed payment 18m
  after effective date
- regular quarterly floating payments

Your curve was built with 1y and 2y swaps, nothing in the middle ? Then yes, your interpolation choice would matter a lot. I would look at 3m forward rates and make sure that they optically make sense.